# What do I need to do to configure Load Balancing between two Win2003 virtual machines running on Hyper-V?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2008, hyper-v, load-balancing

What are the steps to properly configure a NLB cluster between two win2003 virtual machines in Hyper-V, if possible with focus on the network settings?

I have two physical servers running Win2008 Enterprise, with 4 virtual machines each. I need to create a cluster between two virtual machines, where each one resides in a different physical server.

Answer (score 2):

Add a second NIC to each VM and install NLB on the VMs and configure it just as you normally would if they were physical machines.  You can configure NLB with a single NIC in each VM, but it's recommended to use two NICs just like it is on physical machines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is just like a physical Machine.  We have a NLB cluster in VMware ESX, and it works great.  Different host type, but same concept.